# Paypal IPN return variables

Tags: variables, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal IPN to make a subscription transaction. I created a subscription button from my sandbox paypal account, and tested the whole process. The first time i tried, it seemed to work okay, but the second, third and fourth time paypal IPN returned different variables from the first time.

First time important variables were: payment_gross,txn_id

Then it started to give me: amount3,mc_amount3

So payment_gross became amount3 or mc_amount3 and txn_id is not returned anymore. I did not change anything in the generated form. Any suggestions?

Sorry for my English

Thank you

Comment: You should get a subscr_id with subscriptions and txn_id with other payments.

Answer (score 0):

When your ipn callback is called you must always first verify the message with paypal.
Are you doing this? Only then can you be sure it is a legitimate message.

I don't recall ever getting a message without txn_id, and I've used the sandbox a lot for testing.
I can't imagine paypal sending a message without txn_id via IPN as it would not relate to any transaction. The documentation does not mention this as a possibility either.

Anyway [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables) is where I look up all the IPN/PDT variables for my site.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your response. I use that page too for paypal variables and yes i verify for the request to be legitimate. I seemed to figured it out eventually, it seems that paypal sends 2 types of requests one after another when it comes to subscription payments. You can join those two requests through the subscr_id, because they are the same. I don't understand why it does this, maybe the request is too big although i doubt it.